# Getting an error - selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: disconnected: received when I run the Python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-requests

I have this simple `Python` script -
from selenium import `webdriver`
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

```
*driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get('https://marketplace.intacct.com/marketplace?category=a2Ci0000000DijlEAC')*
```

But I am getting an error when I run it.

> raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: disconnected: received Inspector.detached event
> (Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.96)

Tried a lot of things but nothing is working. Please help!